# Совпадение в пределах диапазона

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть база данных Teams. Состоящая из country, capital и teamName. Нужно отобразить те страны в порядке убывания, у которых в названиях столиц ровно две буквы  в диапазоне от "а" до "д".

Проверку на вхождение букв из диапазона понятно как сделать, а вот как узнать что этих букв именно 2?

```
 SELECT country, capital
 FROM Teams
 WHERE capital like '%[а-д]%' 
 ORDER BY country DESC
```

Comment: в принципе ответ на предыдущий ваш вопрос вполне сюда подойдет, только надо не один реплейс сделать, а пять.

Comment: а если диапазон больше будет, например от "а" до "к", делать 12 запросов на реплейс ?

Comment: где вы такие задания то берете? :)

Comment: преподаватель у меня хороший) хочет чтобы руку набили

Comment: руку надо набивать на  нормальных задачах, а не том, что в практике вообще не пригодится никогда. у вас какой то определенный диалект SQL или вы руку набиваете на ANSI SQL?

Comment: если правильно поняла вопрос, то пишу на Microsoft SQL

Comment: правильно поняли. _зы: сомневаюсь что вообще можно вывести такие столицы для диапазона `а-к` это чуть ли не пол алфавита. не просто найти слово, в котором будут только буквы из второй ее части :D_

Comment: Вы знаете версию SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2017 Enterprise

Comment: можно еще попробовать с `PATINDEX` решить, либо вообще разделить названия на буквы и написать обычную группировку к результату

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С точностью до диалекта SQL:

```
 SELECT country, capital
 FROM Teams
 WHERE capital LIKE '%[а-д]%[а-д]%' 
       AND capital NOT LIKE '%[а-д]%[а-д]%[а-д]%'
 ORDER BY country DESC
```

Comment: по идее это должно работать +1

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с SQL Server 2017 можно использовать функцию [TRANSLATE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql):

```
SELECT country, capital
FROM Teams
WHERE len(replace(translate(capital, N'абвгд', '~~~~~'), '~', '')) = len(capital) - 2
ORDER BY country DESC
```